# Long-running tests

Tags: debugging, exception

We get a software package (involving web pages) from a standard provider.  Not sure I can mention the name but it is a big one and keeps track of tickets. Anyway, we do some customization on what we receive.  By "We" I mean the company, not me or my group.  My group only can SQA the pages with Chrome, Java, Eclipse (with debugger) and Selenium.

Anyway, these are big tests (originally written by others who are no longer in the company). They may run 1 1/2 or 2 hours.  Every so often we get a big software update with a lot of changes (xpaths change, or //a changes to //button, or Ids change or lots of other things).

So I can be running a test and it may run for 70 minutes, be about half way done, and then choke on a changed xpath.  To debug, I have to put a breakpoint there, and then run the test from the beginning and wait 70 minutes.  Then if I find a fix, I have to make the fix, terminate the program, run it again for 70 minutes, hope it works, and then wait for the next error, which will take longer to recreate.

There must be other is this situation who have some suggestions on how to debug long-running tests which take a long time before they give error?

I do see the Eclipse debugger can break on exceptions, caught or uncaught.  But since this is testng, aren't all exceptions eventually caught (even by test ng)?  There are a lot of caught exceptions (like sometimes if an element does not go stale that is OK so the exception is caught and ignored.  If an xpath is not visible sometimes that is OK).  So I don't want to break on caught exceptions.

Has anyone else been in this situation and can offer some suggestions?

Comment: First of all such huge automatic test is a overshoot. I would begin with decoupling to be able run smaller tests independently.

Comment: That is best but we have to get SQAs from a different department to do it, and they have other priorities